# Velocity of projectile with both quadratic and constant resistive force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, projectile, drag

Suppose we have a projectile of mass $m$ that impacts a material with velocity $v_0$. As it travels through the material it is subject to the resistive force $F = \alpha v^2 + \beta$.
How can I determine $v(t)$, the velocity of the projectile at time $t$ where $t=0$ is the impact time, and $v(p)$, the velocity of the projectile when it reaches a penetration depth of $p$?

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209760/) question addresses $v(t)$ for an exclusively quadratic resistive force ($\beta = 0$), but is there a more general formula for when there is a constant component?

Comment: If you know how to solve it with $\beta = 0$, you also know how to do it for $\beta \neq0$. The equation is still separable.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: @HiddenBabel Thank you, I think I understand how to determine the equation for v(t) now. But is there an equation for v(p)? I suppose that by calculating $v(t_x)$ and the integral of $v(t)$ from 0 to $t_x$ both instantaneous velocity and and penetration $p_x$ at time $t_x$ would be yielded, and an approximation of $v(p)$ can be made by interpolating multiple $(p_x, v(t_x))$ points, but is there a more direct way?

Comment: @jt2k Once you have the solution for velocity you can integrate it with respect to time to obtain distance (i.e., depth). Find the time the depth is achieved by solving depth == p and plug the time obtained back in the solution for velocity, you’ll get v(p).

Comment: @Newbie I apologize for not being more clear, but what I am asking is if there is a way to get velocity as function of position/penetration depth, not just the velocity at one particular position.

Comment: @jt2k $vdv=adx$ is a good starting point. Note that $a=F/m$ is given as a function of $v$.

Comment: @jt2k I posted an answer. Let me know if it makes sense or there are any errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $vdv=adx$ where $a=F/m=-\frac{\alpha}{m}v^{2}-\frac{\beta}{m}$ we have
$$vdv=(-\frac{\alpha}{m}v^{2}-\frac{\beta}{m})dx\rightarrow \int\frac{v}{\frac{\alpha}{m}v^{2}+\frac{\beta}{m}}dv=-\int dx$$
Defining the new variable $u=\frac{\alpha}{m}v^{2}+\frac{\beta}{m}$ we have $\frac{du}{dv}=2\frac{\alpha}{m}v$. Thus, $vdv=\frac{m}{2\alpha}du$ and the integral reduces to
$$\frac{m}{2\alpha}\int\frac{1}{u}du=-\int dx$$ Subsequently,
$$\frac{m}{2\alpha}\ln u=-x+C$$
We use the initial condition that for $x=0$, $v=v_{0}$ and $u=u_{0}=\frac{\alpha}{m}v_{0}^{2}+\frac{\beta}{m}$. Hence $C=\frac{m}{2\alpha}\ln u_{0}$. With some straightforward algebra you should be able to get
$$u(x)=u_{0}\exp{(-\frac{2\alpha}{m}}x)$$ Let $x=p$ and you'll get $u(p)$. From that you get $v(p)$.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to confirm that the functions for $v(t)$ and $v(p)$ do indeed correspond as expected.

Comment: @jt2k Glad to help!